# С# проблемы с изменением значения переменной

Tags: c#, .net

Возникли проблемы с работой моей программы, переменная `a` не меняет значение с `false` на `true`. Здесь привел упрощенный проблемный кусок. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
class Value
{
    static public bool a = false;
    static string b = "true";

    static public void AChanger()
    {
        if (b == "true")
        {
            a = true;
        }
        else
        {
            a = false;
        }
    }


}



class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Value.AChanger()
    }
}
```

Comment: Это я ошибся, когда забивал код на сайт. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: Метки вопроса: у вас код на си или шарпе?

Comment: А дебаггером пользоваться пробовали? Что идет не так?

Comment: А где собственно находиться метод `AChanger`

Comment: Наверное, Вы слишком упростили код.

Answer (score 7):

> привел упрощенный проблемный кусок

```
<телепатия>
```

Слишком упрощенный. В Вашем реальном коде, объявлена еще одна переменная `a`, которая перекрывает/прячет ту `a`, которую Вы показали в вопросе.

```
</телепатия>
```